# Replace ip partially with x in python

Tags: python

I have several ip addresses like

```
162.1.10.15
160.15.20.222
145.155.222.1
```

I am trying to replace the ip's like below.

```
162.x.xx.xx
160.xx.xx.xxx
145.xxx.xxx.x
```

How to achieve this in python.

Comment: Ever heard of regex in python?

Comment: Yes. I have heard of regex.. being new to python...i am not sure how to approach this problem using regex. Any pointers or hints are highly appreciated

Comment: Highly recommend you checking regex aka regular expressions. They come in clutch when it comes to using them to manipulate strings. Much versatile but takes a little while to understand. Just look up "regex in python" and you will find tons of material to learn from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a slightly simpler solution

```
import re

txt = "192.1.2.3"

x = txt.split(".", 1) # ['192', '1.2.3']
y = x[0] + "." + re.sub(r"\d", "x", x[1])

print(y) # 192.x.x.x
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is also the best one +1.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `re.sub` with a callback function here:

```py
def repl(m):
    return m.group(1) + '.' + re.sub(r'.', 'x', m.group(2)) + '.' + re.sub(r'.', 'x', m.group(3)) + '.' + re.sub(r'.', 'x', m.group(4))

inp = "160.15.20.222"
output = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\b', repl, inp)
print(output)  # 160.xx.xx.xxx
```

In the callback, the idea is to use `re.sub` to surgically replace each digit by `x`.  This keeps the same width of each original number.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the optimize solution but it works for me .

```
import re
Ip_string = "160.15.20.222"
Ip_string = Ip_string.split('.')
Ip_String_x =""
flag = False
for num in Ip_string:
  if flag:
    num = re.sub('\d','x',num)
    Ip_String_x = Ip_String_x + '.'+ num
  else:
    flag = True
    Ip_String_x = num
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Other answers are good, and this single regex works, too:

```py
import re


strings = [
    '162.1.10.15',
    '160.15.20.222',
    '145.155.222.1',
]

for string in strings:
    print(re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\.)|(?<=\.\d)|(?<=\.\d\d))\d', 'x', string))
```

output:

```
162.x.xx.xx
160.xx.xx.xxx
145.xxx.xxx.x
```

#### Explanation

- `(?<=\.)` means following by single dot.
- `(?<=\.\d)` means follwing by single dot and single digit.
- `(?<=\.\d\d)` means following by single dot and double digit.
- `\d` means a digit.
- So, all digits that following by single dot and none/single/double digits are replaced with `'x'`
- `(?<=\.\d{0,2})` or similar patterns are not allowed since look-behind (`(?<=...)`) should has fixed-width.

#### Solution 2

Without `re` module and regex,

```py
for string in strings:
    first, *rest = string.split('.')
    print('.'.join([first, *map(lambda x: 'x' * len(x), rest)]))
```

above code has same result.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about this. Regex is the most versatile and fancy way to write string manipulation codes. But you can also do it by same old for-loops with split and join functions.

```
ip = "162.1.10.15"

#Splitting the IPv4 address using '.' as the delimiter
ip = ip.split(".")

#Converting the substrings to x's except 1st string
for i,val in enumerate(ip[1:]):
    cnt = 0
    for x in val:
        cnt += 1
    ip[i+1] = "x" * cnt

#Combining the substrings back to ip
ip = ".".join(ip)
print(ip)
```

I highly recommend checking Regex but this is also a valid way to go about this task.

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array of IPs to this function:

```
def replace_ips(ip_list):
    r_list=[]
    for i in ip_list:
        first,*other=i.split(".",3)
        r_item=[]
        r_item.append(first)
        for i2 in other:
            r_item.append("x"*len(i2))
        r_list.append(".".join(r_item))
    return r_list
```

In case of your example:

```
print(replace_ips(["162.1.10.15","160.15.20.222","145.155.222.1"]))#==> expected output: ["162.x.xx.xx","160.xx.xx.xxx","145.xxx.xxx.x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner FYI:

```
import re

ips = ['162.1.10.15', '160.15.20.222', '145.155.222.1']
pattern = r'\d{1,3}'
replacement_sign = 'x'

res = [re.sub(pattern, replacement_sign, ip[::-1], 3)[::-1] for ip in ips]

print(res)
```